# Leaving country soon, can I leave my bank accounts open?

Tags: banking, foreign-exchange, turkey, foreign-accounts

I am a Tunisian citizen currently residing in Turkey with a work permit. However, due to a restructuring in the startup I worked for, I've been laid off and my work permit will not be renewed. As it's expiring in a few days, I need to return to Tunisia urgently.

I have several bank accounts in Turkey, denominated in TRY, USD, and EUR. I prefer to keep these accounts open and the funds accessible for a few reasons:

The [Tunisian Dinar (TND) is a closed currency](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tunisian_dinar). While I can easily transfer money into Tunisia, getting it out is a significant challenge.
I'm planning to apply for job opportunities in the EU/UK, so having accessible funds outside Tunisia will be immensely advantageous.

My question is: **Are there any commonly known restrictions or implications for keeping Turkish bank accounts open after losing one's residence status?**

Any advice or personal experiences related to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked your bank(s)? If you're allowed to (by law and banks' policies), that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You might consider asking this on our [expatriates.se] site, where there are people who know about living and working abroad.

Comment: Those comments seem to add up to an Answer...